# Access non-parsed email address with Mikel's Mail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm using Mikel's Mail gem successfully, but I'm trying to pull off the name from an email address without much luck.

If I receive 'Mikel Lindsaar (mikel@test.lindsaar.net)', then I can access mikel@test.lindsaar.net but not 'Mikel Lindsaar'.

I've been using the to/cc/from methods on the mail object itself. I'm not sure how I would use the Mail::Address class in the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/m/mail-2.5.4/Mail/Address.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of what you need:

```
mail = Mail.new do 
  from "Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net>"
end

mail.header[:from].field.display_names #=> ["Mikel Lindsaar"]
```

The above is kind of awkward but works. The `#field` method on the header[:from] returns a `Mail::FromField` which is more or less a `Mail::CommonAddress` which in turn encapsulates a number of `Mail::Address`es. Kind of complicated right? `CommonAddress` has a few handy methods to manipulate that list of addresses.

You could get the same `FromField` instance by

```
mail.from.instance_variable_get("@field")
```

Comment: Big thanks, Nikos. It works well and will do just fine.